# Blink Circles next to Area tag (image map)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, image

I would like to make blinking circles like in example beloww but I would like to use jquery. I have a house which is mapped in HTML, now I want to show user that there is somethig they can click.
See [Example](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/multimedia/en_us/get/reader/Acrobat/1000x463_hover_tooltips_as2.swf) here, this is flash but I am looking for JQuery solution

I would like to do this for following house [see here](http://santehmaster.mdigital.md/index.php?lang=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this Pen a while ago. You can use this.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/pnGAB)**

Comment: Will i be able to use this in my google map, Please guide me @Lokesh Suthar